# How do I have a column of data show multiple responses?

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains survey responses where one of the columns is called Survey Answers. One of the questions allow people to select multiple answers. When multiple answers are selected, the result in the Survey Answers would be displayed as Multiple Answers.

Is there a way to have the data in the Survey Answers column be displayed with all of the answers the customer selected and have it be separated by a comma?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. Read more about one-to-many and many-to-many relations. There are tons of freely available information online. An ugly way of handling it is to use a comma-separated `varchar` column, but I'd advise you to store your distinct answer values in a separate table and then link questions and answers through a gerund.

If you share your table design, I'll update my answer to include a more discrete implementation.